# INSERT INTO sql query not working column undefined

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, pg

```
def self.create_tables
  connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'clients')
  connection.exec('CREATE TABLE client_details (
                Company_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                Company_Name text,
                Company_Telephone text,
                Company_Representitive text,
                Company_Email text,
                Company_Address text,
                Company_Contract_Start_Date text,
                Company_Contract_End_Date text
                )')
end
def self.create_table_data
  connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'clients')
  connection.exec('INSERT INTO client_detail (
  Company_Name,
  Company_Telephone,
  Company_Representitive,
  Company_Email,
  Company_Address,
  Company_Contract_Start_Date,
  Company_Contract_End_Date) 
  VALUES (
  "Monoprix", 
  "1234", 
  "sarah", 
  "dan@dan.com", 
  "this road", 
  "12", 
  "13");')
end
```

When I run the first function it works, when I run the 2nd function I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
         2: from lib/data_generator.rb:22:in `<main>'
         1: from lib/data_generator.rb:6:in `create_table_data'
    lib/data_generator.rb:6:in `async_exec': ERROR:  column"monoprix" does not exist (PG::UndefinedColumn)
    LINE 1: ...act_Start_Date,Company_Contract_End_Date) VALUES (Monoprix, ...
                                                                    ^
```

I don't know why the error is telling me that column 'monoprix' does not exist when I am attempting to INSERT the value 'monoprix' into the COLUMN Company_Name, not 'monoprix'.

However, when I insert the VALUES 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 it works fine.

I'm stumped.

I want to insert 'monoprix' into the column 'Company_Name'.

Comment: You are using double quotes instead of single quotes to delimit strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has come from the `"` quotation marks in the string. You need to either use a backslash to delimit them, as per Mike's answer, or use single ones inside a string and double ones to delimit the string itself as I have done below. Try again replacing them with single quotes: `'`

```
def self.create_tables
  connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'clients')
  connection.exec('CREATE TABLE client_details (
                Company_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                Company_Name text,
                Company_Telephone text,
                Company_Representitive text, 
                    Company_Email text,
                Company_Address text,
                Company_Contract_Start_Date text,
                Company_Contract_End_Date text
                )')
end
def self.create_table_data
  connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'clients')
  connection.exec("INSERT INTO client_detail (
  Company_Name,
  Company_Telephone,
  Company_Representitive,
  Company_Email,
  Company_Address,
  Company_Contract_Start_Date,
  Company_Contract_End_Date) 
  VALUES (
  'Monoprix', 
  '1234', 
  'sarah', 
  'dan@dan.com', 
  'this road', 
  '12', 
  '13');")
end
```

Comment: We must have submitted at the same time.  Try the above, but with escape characters in your string.

Comment: Corrected this in my latest edit, using double for the outer delimiter, single for inner ones.

Comment: Thank you Barry Piccinni and @MikeBaron. I ended up going with Barry as it was 'neater' (a lot of back-slashes), but both ways worked. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
def self.create_tables
  connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'clients')
  connection.exec('CREATE TABLE client_details (
                Company_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                Company_Name text,
                Company_Telephone text,
                Company_Representitive text,
                Company_Email text,
                Company_Address text,
                Company_Contract_Start_Date text,
                Company_Contract_End_Date text
                )')
end
def self.create_table_data
  connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'clients')
  connection.exec('INSERT INTO client_detail (
  Company_Name,
  Company_Telephone,
  Company_Representitive,
  Company_Email,
  Company_Address,
  Company_Contract_Start_Date,
  Company_Contract_End_Date) 
  VALUES (
  \'Monoprix\', 
  \'1234\', 
  \'sarah\', 
  \'dan@dan.com\', 
  \'this road\', 
  \'12\', 
  \'13\');')
end
```

Seems dumb, but gotta check off all the obvious boxes.

Comment: Thank you, i went with Barry's solution, but yours worked as well. Thanks